# Push JSX element as a child of another JSX element inside an Array (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a react app to print a tree-view from an array of nested objects. Each node should be collapsible (open by default). A node may have any number of child nodes. Here is a sample of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Tree View]

I am collecting all node components inside an array and then accessing that collection in render method. Right now all node components are printed at same heirarchy as they are not nested in each other. In the code below, how can I add `<PrintNode treeData={obj}` as a child of `<PrintNode treeData={obj} hasChildNodes={true} />` in the `treeToRender` array?

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PrintNode from './components/PrintNode';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  data = [ // this data will come from another file in real app
    {
      text: 'Parent 1',
      nodes: [
        {
          text: 'Child 1',
          nodes: [
            {
              text: 'Grandchild 1'
            },
            {
              text: 'Grandchild 2'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          text: 'Child 2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: 'Parent 2'
    },
    {
      text: 'Parent 3'
    },
    {
      text: 'Parent 4'
    },
    {
      text: 'Parent 5'
    }
  ];

  treeToRender = [];

  getNextNode(nextData) {
    let key = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nextData.length; i++) {
      let obj = nextData[i];
      if (!obj.nodes) {
        this.treeToRender.push(<PrintNode treeData={obj} />)
        key++;
      }
      else {
        this.treeToRender.push(<PrintNode treeData={obj} hasChildNodes={true} />)
        key++;
        this.getNextNode(obj.nodes);
      }
    }
    return this.treeToRender;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        {this.getNextNode(this.data)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PrintNode.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class PrintNode extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let nodeToRender = '';
        if (this.props.hasChildNodes) {
            nodeToRender = <div className="has-child">{this.props.treeData.text}</div>
        }
        else {
            nodeToRender = <div>{this.props.treeData.text}</div>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.treeData.text}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Please note that each JSX element is an object, not a string which can be easily manipulated.

Also I am getting error "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of App." even though I have added key to PrintNode. Why is this happening?

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rpLw0y6/1/).

Comment: What you'll want to do is not append the component, but put `data` on the `App` `state` object, then update the `state` of `data` inside your `App` component. React will take care of the rest.

Comment: To accomplish what you are after you will need to recursively dive your data and append new PrintNodes to PrintNodes that have children.

Comment: @Kyle Richardson: That's what I have mentioned in my question! But how to implement that in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an updated solution for. I hope this helps you understand how to recursively build JSX objects.

I've provided a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybajxM?editors=1111) as well for you to look at so that you can see the working code.

```
function createTree(data) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                data.map((node) => {
                    return createNode(node);
                })
            }
        </ul>
    );
}

function createNode(data) {
    if (data.nodes) {
        return (
      <li>
        <PrintNode text={ data.text }>{createTree(data.nodes)}</PrintNode>
      </li>
    );
    } else {
        return <PrintNode text={ data.text } />
    }
}

const PrintNode = (props) => {
    return <li>{ props.text }{ props.children }</li>
};

const App = (props) => {
    return createTree(props.data);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={ data } />, document.getElementById("app"));

const data = [
    {
        text: 'Parent 1',
        nodes: [
            {
                text: 'Child 1',
                nodes: [
                    {
                        text: 'Grandchild 1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Grandchild 2'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'Child 2'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'Parent 2'
    },
    {
        text: 'Parent 3'
    },
    {
        text: 'Parent 4'
    },
    {
        text: 'Parent 5'
    }
];
```

Comment: I have added a fiddle. Can you incorporate your code into it?

Comment: I could... but if you do it yourself you will remember how to do it the next time you encounter this situation. Why don't you take a crack at it, and if it's not working for you, post your progress and I can help you along from there.

Comment: I did, but it gives error "Cannot read property 'text' of undefined".

Comment: `data.map((node) => {return createNode(data);});` should probably read `data.map(node => createNode(node))`

Comment: I like to wrap my arguments, and explicitly return. Explicit is always better than implicit. Core concept of programming.